# Download file once - Corrupt file error

Tags: php, html, database, download

What I want to do is to allow only one download per user (one access to a href) For that I have a variable in the user's table, which I do change when the link has been clicked. 
I use "download.php?file=file.xxx" for doing that.

**download.php**

```
$file= basename($_GET['file']);
$root = "documents/rece/";
$path= $root.$file;
echo $path;

if (is_file($path))
{
   header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
   header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
   header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.$file);
   header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
   header('Expires: 0');
   header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
   header('Pragma: public');
   header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($path));
   readfile($path);
}
else
      echo "File error";
   exit();

?>
```

I also update the DDBB and that works. After that I can show or hide the link. The problem is that the downloaded file is corrupted and can't be opened. I will use it with pdf or doc, maybe zip.

Could it be because of the path?

Comment: What if the connection get lost, shouldnt you set the flag once download complete instead on click?

Comment: You are right, i'm obviating that possibility. I'll think it. Anyway my problem is that the files are not correct. I don't know if that's because of the headers (i think they are right) or because of what... Thanks for your comment

Comment: try to check for any BOM character

Comment: Akam, can you tell me please how? Thank you

Comment: Open the file in a text editor and look for leading/trailing white space, leading BOM marker, or obvious PHP error messages

Comment: I pasted it here:http://pastebin.com/LErTSWFK Take a look please

Comment: [Offtop] Don't forget about security. xyz.com/?file=../../../../etc/passwd

Comment: Could you explain it? basename($_GET['file']) can't do the job? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PDF files, as far as I know, start with something like this:

```
%PDF-1.4
```

Yours start with 4 blank lines plus `documents/rece/Form.pdf%PDF-1.4`. You're obviously printing it yourself somewhere before the code you've posted.

Comment: I'll put an analogy. Imagine you take a picture with your cam, you open the resulting JPEG in Notepad++, you type your name and you save the file. What will happen with the picture?

Comment: Right. I thought the file started with headers, and all the code before was not included. Thanks.